# how to find number of subsets which have fixed number of elements?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

If the set $U=\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z\}$, then
how many possible subsets are there in which the number of elements in the subset is $5$? For example:
$s_1=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$,
$s_2=\{a,f,l,k,x\}$, and
$s_3=\{a,c,k,x,y\}$.

How is this generalized to subsets of different sizes?

Comment: Have you ever heard of "permutations and combinations"?

Comment: Or of [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Definition_and_interpretations)?

Answer (score 1):

The set $U$ contains all the letters in the english alphabet. So there are $26$ letters in your set. You seek to find the number of subsets of size $5$. This is a combination problem. When you see the word "subset" think about an unordered selection since sets with the same elements and different orderings of the elements are the same. There are ${26\choose 5}=65780$ subsets of size $5$

In general, let $S$ be a set of $n$ elements. A combination of a set $S$ denotes an unordered selection of the elements of $S$. Let $k$ be a non-negative integer. A $k$-combination of a set $S$ of $n$ elements is understood to be an unordered selection of $k$ of the $n$ objects of $S$. The result is an $k$-combination or a $k$-subset of $S$. So ${n\choose k}={{n!}\over {k!(n-k)!}}$ if $k\leq n$ and ${n\choose k}=0$ if $k>n$.

Answer (score 0):

Its basically the idea of choosing. We use combinations when the order doesn't matter . Here we have been given a set of 26 elements and we have to find the number of possible ways of choosing a subset of 5 elements. Using binomial coefficients it will be $$\binom{26}{5}=65780$$